# How do I upgrade all scoped packages with Yarn?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Is it possible to upgrade all specific scoped packages in the dependencies section of my `package.json` by using the Yarn package manager?

For example:

```
yarn upgrade @scope/*
```

This will upgrade all scoped packages in `yarn.lock` and `package.json` file.

Comment: Do you know if `npm` supports this? If so, what's the syntax?

Comment: Also, which platform is this? Linux (or any Unix-like system) or Windows?

Comment: @Aurora0001: I don't know about the npm support, I used windows. I know its not a valid syntax, just asked is there any option in yarn.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't any way to do this with Yarn. If you want, I could write a short Node script that could search each dependency and run `yarn upgrade` for it. The reason I ask whether npm supports this is because it would make the issue easier to search for, but don't worry if you're not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there's no way to do this currently with Yarn, I've written a very short Node script to do what you want:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var child_process = require('child_process');

var filterRegex = /@angular\/.*/;

fs.readFile('./package.json', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var dependencies = JSON.parse(data)['dependencies'];
    Object.keys(dependencies).forEach(function(dependency) {
        if (filterRegex.test(dependency)) {
            console.log('Upgrading ' + dependency);
            child_process.execSync('yarn upgrade ' + dependency);
        } else {
            console.log('Skipping ' + dependency);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a quick explanation of what that does:

- it loads the `package.json` from the directory that the terminal is currently in
- we then parse the JSON of the `package.json` and get the `"dependencies"` key
- for each dependency, we run the regex specified as the `filterRegex` (if you need to change this or want an explanation of the regex syntax, I would test with [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/). I used `@angular` as an example prefix for the regex)
- if the dependency matches, we run `yarn upgrade [DEPENDENCY]` and log it
- otherwise, we log that it was skipped.

Let me know if you have any trouble with this, but it should solve your issue until the Yarn team come up with something better.

Answer (score 33):

https://github.com/torifat/yarn-update says:

Please use `yarn upgrade-interactive` instead.

Answer (score 15):

In the current version v1.2.1 you can actually use the build in `--scope` flag to upgrade only packages that begin with that scope `yarn upgrade --scope @angular`. Check out more on [yarn upgrade scope](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade#toc-yarn-upgrade-scope-s-scope-latest-pattern) on the official website.

Answer (score 3):

Or better install [yarn-update](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn-update).
I found it very useful.
All you have to do is to run `yarn-update` and then select the packages you want to update.

Answer (score 3):

Code below upgrade all packages of scope to latest version.

```bash
yarn upgrade --scope @scope-name --latest
```

or

```bash
yarn upgrade -S @scope-name --latest
```

Answer (score 2):

`yarn upgrade-interactive` should do the trick for you with an up-to-date version of yarn. This advice is even output when installing the yarn-update package that @valentinvoilean mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

```
yarn upgrade --scope @scopeName --latest

//Example :- 
yarn upgrade --scope @angular --latest
// OR
yarn upgrade -S @angular --latest
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern versions of Yarn (Yarn 2 and newer), you can use `yarn up '@scope/*'`. You don't even need to install the interactive upgrade plugin. It took me way longer than needed to find this! See docs here: https://yarnpkg.com/cli/up Note that `yarn upgrade` was deprecated and doesn't exist in newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) 
after installing it, just run `ncu -u` and then run `yarn`

Comment: This seems to be more like a comment but not an answer. Please see Stack Overflow help [How to answer section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)