# How to bump version in all the packages when using yarn workspaces?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, monorepo

When using `Yarn Workspaces`, we have a project structure like:

```
- package.json
- packages/
    - package-a/
        - package.json
        - index.js
    - package-b/
        - package.json
        - index.js
```

If `package-b` and lots of other packages in this directory are dependent upon `package-a` and I upgrade the version of `package-a` after making some changes, How can I upgrade the version `package-a` in all the dependent packages? Do I have to do it manually or is there a better way?

Comment: This answer to related question might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40792173/84590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59676839) is outdated; now with [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces) you can use [`yarn up <library-name>`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/up) to bump your dependency in all your workspaces.

Answer (score 5):

as i know its not possible for now to manage this with yarn itself.
you can use the **lerna** project https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/version#readme which supports bumping the version of workspaces

## manual (without lerna)

for my existing projects i have done it manually.

**attention: this command sets all workspaces to the same version**

add `postversion` in the scripts block of your root ./package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "version:package-a": "cd packages/package-a && yarn version --new-version $npm_package_version",
    "version:package-b": "cd packages/package-b && yarn version --new-version $npm_package_version",
    "postversion": "yarn version:package-a && yarn version:package-b"
  }
}
```

- now you can run: `yarn version --patch`
- this will bump the version of all your workspaces (package-a & package-b) to the same **version 1.0.1**.

**Update 2022-04-08**

**Solution 1**: It's now simpler to bumb all versions with the use of the `yarn workspace ...` command. In the main `package.json` you have to put the following:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "version": "yarn workspace package-a version --new-version $npm_package_version && yarn workspace package-b version --new-version $npm_package_version"
  }
}
```

If you execute now `yarn version` all the workspace versions are bumped to the same as they inherit from the specified version from the main `package.json` file

**Solution 2**: yarn has a solution for this. but it is still in experiment mode. https://yarnpkg.com/features/release-workflow

Comment: add `--no-git-tag-version` to `version:package-*` to prevent yarn from creating the tag multiple times.
Like so:
 `"version:package-a": "cd packages/package-a && yarn version --new-version $npm_package_version --no-git-tag-version",`